# How to get rid of the mesh of a `MeshRegion` in a same pane

Tags: graphics, regions

```
point = {{(2 2^(1/3))/3, (2 2^(1/3))/3, (2 2^(1/3))/
3}, {-((2 2^(1/3))/3), (2 2^(1/3))/3, (2 2^(1/3))/3}, {(
2 2^(1/3))/3, -((2 2^(1/3))/3), (2 2^(1/3))/3}, {(2 2^(1/3))/3, (
2 2^(1/3))/
3, -((2 2^(1/3))/3)}, {-((2 2^(1/3))/3), -((2 2^(1/3))/3), (
2 2^(1/3))/3}, {-((2 2^(1/3))/3), (2 2^(1/3))/
3, -((2 2^(1/3))/3)}, {(2 2^(1/3))/
3, -((2 2^(1/3))/3), -((2 2^(1/3))/3)}, {-((2 2^(1/3))/3), -((
 2 2^(1/3))/3), -((2 2^(1/3))/3)}, {0, 1/2^(2/3), 2^(
1/3)}, {0, -(1/2^(2/3)), 2^(1/3)}, {0, 1/2^(
2/3), -2^(1/3)}, {0, -(1/2^(2/3)), -2^(1/3)}, {1/2^(2/3), 2^(1/3),
 0}, {-(1/2^(2/3)), 2^(1/3), 0}, {1/2^(2/3), -2^(1/3), 
0}, {-(1/2^(2/3)), -2^(1/3), 0}, {2^(1/3), 0, 1/2^(
2/3)}, {-2^(1/3), 0, 1/2^(2/3)}, {2^(1/3), 
0, -(1/2^(2/3))}, {-2^(1/3), 0, -(1/2^(2/3))}};
reg = ConvexHullMesh[point, MeshCellStyle -> {{1, All} -> Red}]
```

[image]

This current method:

```
poly = MeshPrimitives[ConvexHullMesh[point], 2];
total = Function[part, 
     Select[poly, 
      RegionDistance[InfinitePlane @@ part, RandomPoint[#]] < 
        10^-5 &]] /@ poly // DeleteDuplicatesBy[#, Sort[#] &] &;
g12 = Polygon /@ (#[[
       FindShortestTour[#] // Last]] & /@ (DeleteDuplicates /@ 
       Apply[Sequence, total, {2, 3}])) // 
  Graphics3D[{Yellow, EdgeForm[Red], #}, Boxed -> False] &
```

[image]

Are there more smart method to get rid of the redundant red line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Graphics3D[{Yellow, EdgeForm[Red],Polygon@*VertexList@*Graph /@ 
   FindCycle[NearestNeighborGraph[point // N, 3], {5}, All]}]
```

[image: img]

Answer (score 5):

I would not claim that the following is smarter, but it is different in most respects.  It gathers contiguous triangles with parallel normal vectors, extracts the vertices and eliminates duplicates, constructs polygons from those vertices, and plots the polygons to form the desired object.

```
poly = MeshPrimitives[ConvexHullMesh[point], 2];
cros[x_] := Cross[x[[1, 1]] - x[[1, 3]], x[[1, 2]] - x[[1, 3]]];
GraphicsComplex[#, Polygon@Last@FindShortestTour[#]] & /@ 
    (Union@Flatten[# /. Polygon -> List, 2] & /@ 
    Gather[poly, Norm[Cross[cros[#1], cros[#2]]] < .0001 && 
        Length@Union[#1[[1]], #2[[1]]] < 6 &]);
Graphics3D[Join[{Yellow, EdgeForm[Red]}, %], Boxed -> False]
```

This approach uses `FindShortestTour`, as in the OP's solution, because it is very efficient.  The code above produces a plot identical to that in the question.