# How to automatically pack irregular polyhedra

Tags: graphics3d, polyhedra

We get the tetrakaidecahedron like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104893/21532):

```
pts = {{1 - 2/3*(2^(1/3)), 2 - 2/3*(2^(1/3)), 
    2/3*(2^(1/3))}, {1 - 2/3*(2^(1/3)), -(2 - 2/3*(2^(1/3))), 
    2/3*(2^(1/3))}, {1 - 2/3*(2^(1/3)), 
    2 - 2/3*(2^(1/3)), -2/3*(2^(1/3))}, {1 - 
     2/3*(2^(1/3)), -(2 - 2/3*(2^(1/3))), -2/3*(2^(1/3))}, {1 - 
     2^(1/3), 2 - 1/2*(2^(1/3)), 
    0}, {1 - 2^(1/3), -(2 - 1/2*(2^(1/3))), 0}, {1, 2 - 2^(1/3), 
    1/2*(2^(1/3))}, {1, -(2 - 2^(1/3)), 1/2*(2^(1/3))}, {1, 
    2 - 2^(1/3), -1/2*(2^(1/3))}, {1, -(2 - 2^(1/3)), -1/
      2*(2^(1/3))}, {2/3*(2^(1/3)) - 1, 2/3*(2^(1/3)), 
    2 - 2/3*(2^(1/3))}, {2/3*(2^(1/3)) - 1, -2/3*(2^(1/3)), 
    2 - 2/3*(2^(1/3))}, {2/3*(2^(1/3)) - 1, 
    2/3*(2^(1/3)), -2 + 2/3*(2^(1/3))}, {2/3*(2^(1/3)) - 
     1, -2/3*(2^(1/3)), -2 + 2/3*(2^(1/3))}, {2^(1/3) - 1, 0, 
    2 - 1/2*(2^(1/3))}, {2^(1/3) - 1, 0, -2 + 1/2*(2^(1/3))}, {-1, 
    1/2*(2^(1/3)), 2 - 2^(1/3)}, {-1, -1/2*(2^(1/3)), 
    2 - 2^(1/3)}, {-1, 
    1/2*(2^(1/3)), -2 + 2^(1/3)}, {-1, -1/2*(2^(1/3)), -2 + 
     2^(1/3)}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, -1}, {-1, 1, 0}, {-1, -1, 0}};
poly = MeshPrimitives[ConvexHullMesh[pts], 2];
total = Function[part, 
     Select[poly, 
      RegionDistance[InfinitePlane @@ part, RandomPoint[#]] < 
        10^-5 &]] /@ poly // DeleteDuplicatesBy[#, Sort[#] &] &;
(g14 = Polygon /@ (#[[
        FindShortestTour[#] // Last]] & /@ (DeleteDuplicates /@ 
        Apply[Sequence, total, {2, 3}]))) // 
 Graphics3D[{Yellow, #}, Boxed -> False] &
```

[image]

The same method,we can get the dodecahedron:

```
point12 = {{(2 2^(1/3))/3, (2 2^(1/3))/3, (2 2^(1/3))/
    3}, {-((2 2^(1/3))/3), (2 2^(1/3))/3, (2 2^(1/3))/3}, {(
    2 2^(1/3))/3, -((2 2^(1/3))/3), (2 2^(1/3))/3}, {(2 2^(1/3))/3, (
    2 2^(1/3))/
    3, -((2 2^(1/3))/3)}, {-((2 2^(1/3))/3), -((2 2^(1/3))/3), (
    2 2^(1/3))/3}, {-((2 2^(1/3))/3), (2 2^(1/3))/
    3, -((2 2^(1/3))/3)}, {(2 2^(1/3))/
    3, -((2 2^(1/3))/3), -((2 2^(1/3))/3)}, {-((2 2^(1/3))/3), -((
     2 2^(1/3))/3), -((2 2^(1/3))/3)}, {0, 1/2^(2/3), 2^(
    1/3)}, {0, -(1/2^(2/3)), 2^(1/3)}, {0, 1/2^(
    2/3), -2^(1/3)}, {0, -(1/2^(2/3)), -2^(1/3)}, {1/2^(2/3), 2^(1/3),
     0}, {-(1/2^(2/3)), 2^(1/3), 0}, {1/2^(2/3), -2^(1/3), 
    0}, {-(1/2^(2/3)), -2^(1/3), 0}, {2^(1/3), 0, 1/2^(
    2/3)}, {-2^(1/3), 0, 1/2^(2/3)}, {2^(1/3), 
    0, -(1/2^(2/3))}, {-2^(1/3), 0, -(1/2^(2/3))}};
poly = MeshPrimitives[ConvexHullMesh[point12], 2];
total = Function[part, 
     Select[poly, 
      RegionDistance[InfinitePlane @@ part, RandomPoint[#]] < 
        10^-5 &]] /@ poly // DeleteDuplicatesBy[#, Sort[#] &] &;
(g12 = Polygon /@ (#[[
        FindShortestTour[#] // Last]] & /@ (DeleteDuplicates /@ 
        Apply[Sequence, total, {2, 3}]))) // 
 Graphics3D[{Red, #}, Boxed -> False] &
```

[image]

Then we make a `g4` that compose of four `g14`

```
{g4 = MapAt[Rotate[#, 90 \[Degree], {1, 0, 0}] &, 
    Table[Translate[g14, n {2, 0, 0}], {n, 0, 3}], {{2}, {4}}]} // 
 Graphics3D[{Yellow, #}, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
   Boxed -> False, AxesStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, Axes -> True] &
```

[image]

Rotate and the `g14` to a fit position in the second floor.

```
Graphics3D[{Yellow, 
  g1490 = Rotate[Rotate[g14, 90 \[Degree], {0, 1, 0}], 
    90 \[Degree], {0, 0, 1}]}, Boxed -> False, 
 AxesStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, Axes -> True, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]
```

[image]

Then I put an adequate built seamless polyhedron

```
Graphics3D[{Yellow, 
  g4s = Rotate[
    Translate[
     Rotate[g4, 90 \[Degree], {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}], {1, 1, 2}], 
    90 \[Degree], {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 2}], 
  Table[Translate[g4, {0, 4*n, 0}], {n, 0, 2}], 
  Translate[g4s, {4, 0, 0}], Red, 
  Table[Translate[
    Table[Translate[Translate[g12, {3, 0, 2}], {0, 4*n, 0}], {n, 0, 
      2}], {4*n, 0, 0}], {n, 0, 1}], 
  Table[Translate[
    Table[Translate[g1490, {-1 + 4 n, 2, 1}], {n, 0, 2}], {0, 4*n, 
     0}], {n, 0, 1}]}, AxesStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, Axes -> True, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]
```

[image]

Yes, I made it .But I think this solution by roate and translate every polyhedron is very silly. So can anyone give a more smarter way which can **automated heap up it** when give each of six tetrakaidecahedron and two dodecahedron? My idea is preliminary **get the most suitable position by the result shape's the minimum convex hull volume and its the smallest surface area** to adjust every polyhedron. Can anything suggetion be proposed??

For the target request, I take a try like following:

```
testg4 = ConvexHullMesh[pts];
NMinimize[{RegionUnion[testg4, 
       newtestg4 = 
        TransformedRegion[testg4, 
         AffineTransform[{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}}]]] // 
      MeshPrimitives[#, 0] & // Level[#, {2}] & // ConvexHullMesh // 
   Volume, RegionDimension[RegionIntersection[testg4, newtestg4]] != 
   3}, {a, b, c, d, e, f}]
```

But I get some information of some syntax error.

Comment: The errors are `{ TransformedRegion::rnimpl, RegionUnion::dims, Volume::reg, RegionIntersection::dims, RegionDimension::reg }` in that evaluation order. It seems that `TransformedRegion` is receiving an incorrect input type `BoundaryMeshRegion` and so it is returning unevaluated (rnimpl is not implemented) the remaining errors seem the consequence of this first which could be solved by extracting subexpressions with `Head = Polygon`  from `BoundaryMeshRegion`, (using Cases or Select maybe) and use these subexpressions as the first argument for `TransformedRegion` instead.